# How do UV layers and materials relate to each other?

Tags: texturing, uv

So I understand that one mesh can have more than one UV and also more than one material.

What I haven’t figured yet is - how does one define which material uses which UV in texturing the mesh.

How does that work? Ideally both via the UI and via python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give a couple examples where I use myself more than one material for an object and also more than one UV for a Material:

Case 1) Multiple materials for an objet is probably more common than multiple UV's and in this case I use two materials for a mesh (one rough and one smooth)[image]

Case 2) Multiple UV's in a material (and an object) comes very useful when you want to use decals and in this case I use a normal decal to simulate an engraving. Here we will have the object with two UV's but also the material will make use of the second UV (by the uv node in the material that is linked to the image that will mnake the bump indicating in which specific UV that image will be laid upon leaving the first UV for the material properties). You can also use this to make a detail map.[image]
And I can save myself a headache in geometry! [image] In case you were wondering, if I disconnect the UV map node the engraving goes all over the place because it will deploy in the first UV by default if not specified otherwise[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, every object has a single UV called "UVMap".  You can find it in the properties editor, Object Data Properties tab, in the *UV Maps* panel:

[image: Location of UVMap]

In the same panel, or in the UV Editor window, you can assign additional UVs to an object, giving each a different name.

When you create a material using nodes in the shader editor, many of the nodes have a *Vector* or similar input, like this image texture:

[image: Image texture showing vector input]

There are two ways to tell the node to use a UV.  If you want to use the default UVMap, then you plug in a *Texture Coordinate* node's *UV* output:

[image: Texture Coordinate node used for UV]

The other way is to use a *UV Map* node and set the name of the UV you want to use in that node:

[image: UV Map node]

as you can see, you can use the UV Map mode to plug in the default map, or you can change the name to the other map you created.